# Add start and End Location on Google map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

i want to first show start marker on map view and when user tap this marker show end marker for end location. there is my code for add two marker, but thats not working. and i can't detect user select start location or end.

```
var startMarker:GMSMarker!

var endMarker:GMSMarker!

     func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {

        let latitude = mapView.camera.target.latitude
        let longitude = mapView.camera.target.longitude
        centerMapCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        self.placeMarkerOnCenter(centerMapCoordinate:centerMapCoordinate)

      }
      func placeMarkerOnCenter(centerMapCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        if startMarker:GMSMarker == nil {
          startMarker:GMSMarker = GMSMarker()
        }

        if endMarker == nil {
          endMarker = GMSMarker()
        }
        endMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.2509803922, blue: 0.5058823529, alpha: 1))
        endMarker.position = centerMapCoordinate
        endMarker.map = self.mapView

        startMarker.position = centerMapCoordinate
        startMarker.map = self.mapView
        startMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137503, green: 0.8235294223, blue: 0.4196078479, alpha: 1))

      }
```

how can hide end marker , and show this when user tap and Specify the start location.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Edited Code.

```
    var startMarker:GMSMarker!

   var endMarker:GMSMarker!

 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {

    let latitude = mapView.camera.target.latitude
    let longitude = mapView.camera.target.longitude
    centerMapCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    self.placeMarkerOnCenter(centerMapCoordinate:centerMapCoordinate)

  }
  func placeMarkerOnCenter(centerMapCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    if startMarker:GMSMarker == nil {
      startMarker:GMSMarker = GMSMarker()
    }

    if endMarker == nil {
      endMarker = GMSMarker()
    }

    startMarker.position = centerMapCoordinate
    startMarker.map = self.mapView
    startMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137503, green: 0.8235294223, blue: 0.4196078479, alpha: 1))


    endMarker.position = centerMapCoordinate

  }
```

And now add another Function that is given below

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {

  startMarker.map = nil

  endMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.2509803922, blue: 0.5058823529, alpha: 1))
  endMarker.map = self.mapView

  return true
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for reply. i try your code but when taped start marker     startMarker.map = nil not working and when end marker show start marker don't hidden from map.